# calling non-static method without instance variable

Tags: java

I’m trying to figure out the below code. `ImageIcone` called “non-static method” `getImage()` according to Java API without any instance variable:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Image img = new ImageIcon("imgtest.jpg", "description...").getImage();
    g.drawImage(img,3,4,this);
}
```

Comment: What? What non static method? What is it invoked on?

Comment: getImage() in ImageIcon class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
new ImageIcon("imgtest.jpg", "description...")
```

creates an instance. The `getImage()` method is invoked on that instance and then all references to that instance are lost. The object can then be garbage collected if it is unreachable.

Remember, all you need to invoke an instance method is an expression that resolves to an object reference. A variable of a reference type is one such expression. A constructor invocation is another such expression. An invocation of a method with a return type of some reference type is also such an expression.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The `Image` has a reference to the `ImageIcon` it came from? I don't know this API at all.

Comment: Because [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) is abstract. See also [ImageIcon.getImage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage%28%29)

Comment: thanks guys. also I hadn't noticed that it is an abstract class

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an 'instance *variable*.' You only need an *instance*, and `new ImageIcon("imgtest.jpg", "description...")` is the instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,you are creating an anonymous object of ImageIcon class by using the code `new ImageIcon("imgtest.jpg", "description...")`. Since you are not going to use that object in future,that's why you are opting to create an anonymous object.